# Is it possible to create new account in SmartContract?

Tags: smart-contract

we can create new account using cleos .

```
cleos system newaccount <myacount> <newaccount> <new EOS Public key> <new EOS Public key> --stake-net "0.1 EOS"  --stake-cpu "0.1 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 4
```

I want to create new account using my smart contract. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can refer [smart_account_creator](https://github.com/angelol/smart_account_creator)

[Relevant bit](https://github.com/angelol/smart_account_creator/blob/master/smart_account_creator.cpp#L79-L82):

```
// create account
INLINE_ACTION_SENDER(call::eosio, newaccount)
(N(eosio), {{_self, N(active)}},
 {_self, account_to_create, owner_auth, active_auth});
```

Comment: how do you create public and private key pairs?